# Mysql SELECT different

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a question.
My database table is something like this:

---

```
| ID  | Name             | Value |  param  |
|  1  | Michael          | 290   |    X    |
|  2  | John             | 300   |    X    |
|  3  | Michael          | 270   |    X    |
|  4  | John             | 280   |    X    |
|  5  | Michael          | 256   |    Y    |
|  6  | Michael          | 230   |    Y    |
 ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
```

So, I want to use a form to select the latest rows with different param but equal name.
For example, if I search for "Michael", I want to use PHP to show the latest value for the param X and the latest value for the param Y (returning 2 rows).

```
Michael: Param Y: 230
Michael: Param X: 270
```

And if I search for "John" I get:

```
John: Param X: 280.
```

The code

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE name = 'Michael' ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Now I just want for it to select only the latest rows with different param.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the approaches listed won't work with n variable "params". I think something similar may work:

```
SELECT
t.*
FROM Table1 t
JOIN
(SELECT 
           max(id) AS maxid
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY name,param) x
on x.maxid = t.id
WHERE name='Michael'
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64dc4/11

Comment: @user1477040 Sorry, my code was *wrong*, **see edited version now**.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION
  `SELECT * From table WHERE name='Michael' AND PARAM='X'  ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1

     UNION

   SELECT * From table WHERE name='Michael' AND PARAM='Y'  ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: This is ok but cannot address a general number of params.

Answer (score 0):

use LIMIT if you want to select just one row ( hope i understood the question )

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE name = 'Michael' AND param = 'x' ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE name = 'Michael' AND param = 'y' ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: I want for it to show the 2 results for Michael (the value for the param X and Y)

Comment: @FSP Do you have always 1 or 2 params?